# Simple polymer example does not work on Firefox ESR 52.8.0

Tags: firefox, polymer

I'm trying to use webComponents using polymer 3.0.

On chrome everything seems fine but i can't get a pretty simple example to work on firefox ESR 52.8.0.

Here us the example:

https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/JooAma

On firefox nothing happens, meaning, the component custom-element does not get replaced by the html "We are elements in custom-element's local DOM"

Comment: I tested and its working quite good at Firefox with provided link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the screen capture, its working quite good. [image]

Comment: Hey HakanC, witch version of Firefox did you test it ?

Comment: I am far away from that computer. But when I open to use, its updated by itself, I mean it is the latest ver.